# Seasoning Mineral B Pan

Tags: cast-iron, seasoning-pans

Is the strategy for seasoning a mineral B pan the same as as standard cast iron pan? Is the oiling/baking step necessary? Or do you just let the cooking process season it gradually?

This is the pan in question: http://www.debuyer.com/en/products/mineral-b-element-round-fry-pan

Answer (score 2):

Per the  [manual](http://www.debuyer.com/sites/default/files/manuals/deBuyer_Poeles-acier_Instructions_INTL.pdf)  for your MINERAL B pan, you should season it as follows:

> Seasoning: preparing your frying pan
>
> Pour about one millimeter of oil -just to cover the bottom of the pan- and heat it until smoke appears. Next, thrown away the oil in a pan and wipe your pan with paper towels . The more the pan is used, the better the performance. The darker it becomes the better it is for natural nonstick properties.

The manual continues on with use and care instructions.

Comment: So is it best to avoid cooking with acid? No deglazing the pan after a sear?

Comment: FWIW, I have carbon steel crepe pans, and they're not seasoned at all.

Answer (score 2):

In general carbon steel pans should be treated just like cast iron. The only difference I would note is that carbon steel is thinner and is not as warp resistant as cast iron. That said, carbon steel is more malleable and can be pounded flat with little risk or cracking, which cannot be said for cast iron.