# de buyer mineral b carbon steel seasoning

Tags: seasoning-pans, carbon-steel

I bought a mineral b carbon steel pan some time ago and I've cooked with it probably about +-20 times (pretty much use it for steaks). I've been religious about seasoning it after every use using the following method:

- Rinse with hot water and wipe dry.
- Put back on stove top and reheat and ensure completely dried through.
- Wipe on a thin layer of flaxseed oil.

Here is a pic of my pan currently:

[image]

Some questions I have:

- Are the brown (rusty looking) areas quite normal? I'm certain it's not rust as I've taken a lot of care to prevent that, although if I smell closely it does have a slight rusty/metallic smell.
- The only area of the pan that seems to develop some kind of patina is the center as you can see. How do I get that slick black finish over the entire pan? Will that just come from time & use or is my seasoning method incorrect?
- The patina seems quite flaky...is this normal?

Thank you for any info/feedback provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same pan. Are you following the instructions that come with it?

- The center is too burned.
- Flaky is not good.
- The border is not seasoned.
- The border is not rusty.

Is your fire big enough for the pan?

You should clean the pan (thorough scrub with salt) and re-season. See [this Q&A](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56998/seasoning-mineral-b-pan)

Comment: Thanks. I've done the salt scrubbing and re-seasoned it a few times. It's looking a lot better :)